# 'I would be grateful if you ...' or 'I will be grateful ...'?

Tags: word-choice, tenses

What is the difference between "I would be really grateful" and "I will be really grateful"? In particular, which one should be followed  with "could"? I mean like this "I would be really grateful if you could answer" or  "I will be really grateful if you could answer": which one should I use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A previous question asked 'Which dialects of English consider “would” to be a polite form of “will”?' I'd say it's a virtually universal pragmatic device to use 'would' where 'will' would appear the logical choice (though there are probably some situations where using it might be confusing).

Here, 'I will ...' might sound too presumptuous for some, getting too close to assuming compliance. But I'd say that it's a matter of pragmatics rather than grammar (ie don't worry about breaking 'rules' that might have been suggested in some 50-year-old book).

Where there is no sense in hedging, 'will' is quite acceptable, but doesn't pair with 'could':

'I will be really grateful if Limeside Council answers.'

Rob De Decker, at [Grammar.ccc.comm](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm1), agrees that politeness-marking can trump expected usage here, though he says that 'will' can also function as a politeness marker [where volition rather than mere future possibility is obviously implied]:

> The conditional construction does not normally use *will* or *would*
>   in if-clauses.
>
> EXCEPTION: If *will* or *would* express willingness [/ mark politeness],
>   as in requests, they can be used in if-clauses.
>
> e.g. If you will come this way, the manager will see you now.
>
> I would [/should] be grateful if you would [/could] give me a little
>   help.

Comment: so i should use i would

Comment: .... I would :)

Comment: The position is exactly the same in French. *Veuillez* (would) is far more polite that *Voulez*, which implies the same sort of thing as *will you*.

Comment: @WS2 And they have real rules over there. Is it a criminal offence to use the less polite version?

Comment: In my opinion, a pragmatic factor becomes part of grammar when it becomes so conventional that every competent native speaker of the language conforms to it.  And the politeness difference between "will" and "would" has become completely conventional in English.

Comment: Yes, but _you_ can go around making sure that there's not a single 'competent native speaker' refusing / failing to conform to this usage. You'll have to establish 'competence' by some independent test to avoid circularity of argument, of course. And then [CaliforniaJim @ EnglishForums](https://www.englishforums.com/English/WouldWill/bzmkxc/post.htm) comes up with a twist _I_'d not considered: 'To be completely polite, as with strangers, use "would" and "could". To be more casual, as with people you know well, you can use "will" and "can", but even then, "would" and "could" are commonly used.'

Answer (score 3):

*I would* is usually more polite. It gives more of the idea *I understand if you cannot help me.*

*I will* sometimes gives an idea like *You must help me* or *I expect you to help me*.

We more often use *very* instead of *really,* but *really* is ok. It is also ok to just say *grateful* without *really* or *very,* because *grateful* is already a strong word by itself.

You can use *would* or *could* after *you* (see below). If you do not use *would* or *could*, then you use the past participle (past form of the verb), like *helped* in the last example below.

Here are some correct expressions:

> I would be [very] grateful if you could help me practice English.
>
> I would be [very] grateful if you would help me carry this piano upstairs.
>
> I would be [very] grateful if you helped me clean my room.

Answer (score 1):

Will is incorrect with could, but it's very much context. Making the jump would to will.. De-subjunctivization(?if I may)
Snaps it into the present. Warm, friendly. It's a little bit enthusiastic puppy.. To my ears.
To me, would is the normal one. Will is the shocker to be used for effect.