# Will/would be able to

Tags: grammar, american-english, tenses, sentence, conversation

My friend: I am ready to go to any country in the world if there's a treatment.

Me: There's a hospital in the US – they WOULD/WILL be able to treat this.

What's the difference between WOULD BE and WILL BE here?
TIA. 
I know there are a lot of questions about will/would but most of them are about which one's more polite. And I don't think mine has anything to do with politeness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['I would be grateful if you ...' or 'I will be grateful ...'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226101/i-would-be-grateful-if-you-or-i-will-be-grateful)

Answer (score 1):

They generally mean the same thing, however "would be" implies that it is presumed based on the speaker's understanding, not necessarily acknowledged fact. For example, "would be" has a similar meaning to me as "There's a hospital in the US – I believe that they should be able to treat this."
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would

Comment: So will be is when you're certain that the hospital can treat the deseas?

Comment: To my ears, yes, but "would be" has a similar meaning, just less strong.