# Would not be able to versus will not be able to

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, indirect-speech, backshifting, will-would

> Linda phoned and explained that she **would not** be able to come to the party the next day because she was still sick.

Why do we use **would not** instead of **will not**?

Comment: Because it's slightly more polite in giving an excuse. _Will not be able to_ simply refers to the future, without any presupposition. _Would not be able to_ refers to the past tense of _phoned and explained_, so it's a standard indirect speech tactic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will/would be able to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503253/will-would-be-able-to)

Answer (score 1):

Because the sentence is in the past tense. From the point of view of the past tense, the future is expressed with "would" rather than "will."

If the sentence began with "Linda phones and explains that," you'd use "will not be able."

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Because it's slightly more polite in giving an excuse. *Will not be able to* simply refers to the future, without any presupposition. *Would not be able to* refers to the past tense of *phoned and explained*, so it's a standard indirect speech tactic.